# Is 眠たい an adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I was told 眠たい was an adjective, and that it is an exceptional case. How does it work as an adjective and what is its relation to the verb 眠る?

Comment: '眠たい' is a colloquial version of '眠い', 'sleepy.' Maybe it has something to do with '眠りたい'(want to sleep), no? (Hmm... maybe not)

Comment: What do you mean by "an exceptional case"

Comment: @fefe in that it is related to a verb.

Comment: There is a somewhat similar case with 煙たい. (Conjugations can be described as 'irregular'. I'm not sure if it's useful to talk of derivations as 'irregular'.

Comment: @Bathrobe san, Ah, 煙い and 煙たい. 眠い and 眠たい. Then 重い and 重たい, right? What else...

Comment: Nice, Chocolate, I didn't think of 重たい. But I can't think of any others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, 眠たい is an adjective. It's a synonym of 眠い, meaning "sleepy." ([大辞泉 entry here](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%9C%A0%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0&index=115203100000&pagenum=1).)

From what I can find (specifically, [大辞林's explanation)](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%AD%E3%81%B6%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss), 眠たい is in fact related to 眠る, but the 「〜たい」 here is different from the desiderative "I want to" 「〜たい」. This 「〜たい」 is a shortened form of 甚{いた}い (or いたし, in its original form in older Japanese), which is a 連用形 verb ending in classical Japanese meaning "extremely X, where X is the state related to the verb." Here, this "state" is sleepiness. Note that this 甚{いた}い can attach to verbs and give them an emphatic adjectival meaning, and does not attach to adjectives.

めでたい (happy, fortunate) has a similar etymology: 愛{め}で (from the 連用形 of 愛{め}ず, the old form of 愛する) ＋　甚{いた}し.

Edit: Just to clarify, the original form of 眠たい was 眠{ねぶ}り甚{いた}し, but a combination of phonetic drift and other factors led it to eventually evolve into its current form.

Answer (score 1):

It is an i-adjective because it conjugates as so.

> 眠たい, 眠たかった, 眠たくない, ...

Its relation to the verb `眠る` cannot be handled systematically within derivational morphology. The stem of `眠る` is `nemur-`, whereas `眠たい` only uses a portion (`nemu-`) of it. So it has to be considered that this formation is idiosyncratic, not systematic. Note that the meaning is also idiosyncratic.

Comment: 「眠くない」は、「眠たくない」では・・？（「眠たい、眠たかった、眠たくない」と「眠い、眠かった、眠くない」がセットになると・・）