# Putting た in i-adjectives?

Tags: word-choice

I was looking at a jisho.org example sentence for [軽]{かる}い, and I was a bit confused about **[重]{おも}たそう**.

> えりのスーツケースは **[重]{おも}たそう** だが、[実際]{じっさい}はとても[軽]{かる}い。
> Although Eri's suitcase looks heavy, it's actually very light.

I figured out that そう was for "looking like," but the た confused me... I then learned that [重]{おも}たい is just another form of [重]{おも}い. During my research, I found another adjective like this from a Maggie Sensei lesson: [眠]{ねむ}い／[眠]{ねむ}たい.

So now I'm wondering two things:

1. What are the differences between the adjectives ending in い and たい?
2. Do all i-adjectives have such a pair?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Difference between 重い and 重たい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/397/43676)

Comment: And this. [Is 眠たい an adjective?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4391/43676)

Answer (score 1):

1. I can only answer based on your examples, but, at least for them, I think the "ta"-versions emphasize that the property (e.g. heavy) is "a problem", i.e. is something "negative" (=omotai since it's hard to carry), so most likely that is valid also for other similar ones, assuming they exist.
2. No, far from all, I think they are very rare. Omotai is used often. IMHO nemutai a lot less. At least now I can't come up with other examples.